# How can I get libicui18n.so.36 DEB?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

During install PyICU
ImportError : libicui18n.so.36 is occurred, No such directory is shown on terminal of Ubuntu.
without it, I can not Install PyICU
somebody help me please ...

Answer (score 0):

i guess you tried to install pyicu by hand, on ubuntu you may want to use the existing packages:

in your terminal as root:

```
$ apt-get install python-pyicu
```